# Regex for matching text only contain whitespaces and br tag

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a string like this

```
                       <br />                     <br />                <br />
```

or sometimes

```
            <br />          <br />
```

or

```
            <br />
```

how can check if string is only contain whitespace and br in Javascript?
EX: 
if(/\s*/.test(content)){
}

Comment: I would've thought it's be trivial: `/^(\s|<br[^>]*>)+$/i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you want to check for and allow, whitespace and `<br />`, so that suggests an alternation allowing zero or more repeats, anchored at both ends:

```
if(/^(?:\s|<br \/>)*$/.test(content)){ }
```

that means:

- `^` - start of input
- `(?:...)` - a non-capturing group
- `\s` - any single whitespace character
- `|` - alternation, allows the things on either side of it
- `<br \/>` - match the literal string `<br />` (note that we had to escape the `/`)
- `*` - zero or more of the thing that went before, the non-capturing group
- `$` - end of input

If there's a chance the space or solidus within the tag may not be there, or the space may be repeated, then:

```
if(/^(?:\s|<br *\/?>)*$/.test(content)){ }
```

Adding the `*` after the space lets there be zero, or multiple, spaces; adding the `?` after the solidus (`/`) lets it be there (once) or not.

**Note:** The above doesn't allow for any attributes on the `br` tag, e.g. `<br class="foo" />`, `<br data-foo="bar"/>`, etc. It also matches empty strings.

To allow for attributes but continue to match empty strings:

```
if(/^(?:\s|<br[^>]*>)*$/.test(content)){ }
// Change ----^^^^
```

To allow for attributes and *disallow* empty strings (must have at least one whitespace, or one `br` tag):

```
if(/^(?:\s|<br[^>]*>)+$/.test(content)){ }
// Change ------- ---^
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets take this string for example:

```
var input = "    <br />   ";
```

First of all I would prefer to remove all white space from the input, that way we don't have to worry about making the regex check for these:

```
var testData = input.replace(/\s/g, '');
//in this example, testData will now be "<br/>"
```

The you can perform a regex to check for the existence of `<br/>` only:

```
var regex = /^(?:<br\/>)*$/;
var isValid = regex.test(testData);
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jD2V4/)

Comment: FWIW: No need for the `replace`, or for the capture group on the final test.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Actually the capture group seems to be required (try remove it from my fiddle link). I know the replace isn't needed, I just hate working with messy input, and I like to keep my regexes as small as possible - or try to avoid having to use them at all

Comment: @ musefan: You need a *group*, but not a capture group, so the `*` applies to the whole thing: `var regex = /^(?:<br\/>)*$/;` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jD2V4/1/) (capture groups in theory make more work for the rex engine, although I'd hope that `test` would optimize them out!).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I see, misunderstood you. Will chuck it in

Answer (score -1):

```
"^\s*<br />$"
```

Gives you the lines with any amount of whitespace (including enters and tabs!) and ending with "
"